# Image File path to server not C: drive MVC5

Tags: c#, image, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that uploads images, I am trying to get the path to store on the server and not on my C:drive. Below is the code in the controller:

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        if (file != null)
        {
            string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");

            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(physicalPath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalPath);

                string physicalFullPath = Path.Combine(physicalPath, ImageName);

                file.SaveAs(physicalFullPath);

                customer.CustomerLogo = ImageName;
                customer.CustomerLogoPath = physicalFullPath;
                db.Customers.Add(customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return View("Error",e.Message );
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

[image]

It's currently being stored like this(See above Image) I need the path to be "admin.loyaltyworx.co.za\Images\jeep.jpg" How can I achieve this?

Comment: A possible duplicate question. Please check the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838914/c-sharp-save-files-to-folder-on-server-instead-of-local) :

Comment: You have accepted an answer which is completely wrong. You need to use `Server.MapPath("~/Images/");` otherwise you will never be able to access the image when you try and read it (and your only seeing that path because your creating the images on your local machine, which of course you will not be once you publish the app).

Comment: @StephenMuecke,the answer I accepted I tried out of course and it works even after I published.

Comment: Its hard-coding the path. DO NOT do that!

Comment: Ah I see, when I leave it as Server.MapPath("~/Images/") it didn't get saved onto the server and is unreadable once published. Do you have a suggestion on a better solution ?

Comment: string physicalPath = "\\admin.loyaltyworx.co.za\\Images"; this is my code currently

Comment: You do not need that at all. You could just save the path into the data base as `customer.CustomerLogoPath = Path.Combine("~/Images", ImageName);` and then when you want to access it (e.g. for use in an `<img>` tag in a view), then you can use `Server.MapPath(model.CustomerLogoPath)` so it always points to the correct location no mater where you publish your app. `Server.MapPath()` should always be used to map the relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
string physicalPath = "c:\\admin.loyaltyworx.co.za\\Images";
```

Instead of

```
string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
```

Comment: I dont want it to store on my C drive, just straight to the server

Comment: I dont get it, website is on server right? then it will use drive `C:` of the server

Comment: I tried your way, it returned an error: 'c:/admin.loyaltyworx.co.za/Images' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl I corrected my answer. please have a look at it.

Comment: What did you change? Its the same

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl removed the ` Server.MapPath`